# JSON AJAX undefined item

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I have got a problem with displaying the JSON via AJAX.

The feed isn't displaying - the browser says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

I guess I've got something wrong in these:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var news = '<h1>' + item.posts.title + '</h1>' 
                + '<p>' + item.posts.content + '</p>' 
                + '<p>' + item.posts.custom_fields.ecpt_chill + '</p>';
```

↪ [See the full code in action at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What is your server side technology here? .Net, something else?  We need to see the actual returned data.

Comment: FYI, in your fiddle, this ` alert(item);` alerts "ok"...so you have something server side to address.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am using wordpress (PHP) to load data into DB. If you can try to copy and paste the json feed itself - it works fine in browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting means that `typeof item.posts` is `undefined`; e.g. it's not set to any value.

To test what you're getting back from the server, place the following line right before `$.each(data, …`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

You can then view the JSON that is returned by the web server.

By the way, you've set the request type to `POST`. The right method in this case is `GET`.

The following JSON is returned:

```
{"status":"ok","count":1,"count_total":1,"pages":1,"posts":[{"id":587,"type":"weather","slug":"conditions-for-magnitogorsk-ru-at-329-am-yekt","url":"http://www.domain.com/weather/conditions-for-magnitogorsk-ru-at-329-am-yekt/","status":"publish","title":"Conditions for Magnitogorsk, RU at 3:29 am YEKT","title_plain":"Conditions for Magnitogorsk, RU at 3:29 am YEKT","content":"<p><img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/20.gif\" /><br />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />\nFog, -28 C<BR /><br />\n<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR /><br />\nWed &#8211; Partly Cloudy. High: -15 Low: -26<br />\nThu &#8211; Mostly Sunny. High: -20 Low: -24</p>\n<p><a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Magnitogorsk__RU/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/RSXX0058_c.html\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR /><BR /><br />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\">The Weather Channel</a>)</p>\n","excerpt":"Current Conditions: Fog, -28 C Forecast: Wed &#8211; Partly Cloudy. High: -15 Low: -26 Thu &#8211; Mostly Sunny. High: -20 Low: -24 Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather (provided by The Weather Channel)","date":"2012-12-11 22:29:00","modified":"2012-12-21 14:06:27","categories":[],"tags":[],"author":{"id":1,"url":"","description":""},"comments":[],"attachments":[],"comment_count":0,"comment_status":"closed","custom_fields":{"ecpt_chill":["eqweqwe"]}}]}
```

Formatted:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 1,
  "count_total": 1,
  "pages": 1,
  "posts": [{
      "id": 587,
      "type": "weather",
      "slug": "conditions-for-magnitogorsk-ru-at-329-am-yekt",
      "url": "http://www.cityfacts.pro/weather/conditions-for-magnitogorsk-ru-at-329-am-yekt/",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "Conditions for Magnitogorsk, RU at 3:29 am YEKT",
      "title_plain": "Conditions for Magnitogorsk, RU at 3:29 am YEKT",
      "content": "<p><img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/20.gif\" /><br />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />\nFog, -28 C<BR /><br />\n<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR /><br />\nWed &#8211; Partly Cloudy. High: -15 Low: -26<br />\nThu &#8211; Mostly Sunny. High: -20 Low: -24</p>\n<p><a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Magnitogorsk__RU/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/RSXX0058_c.html\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR /><BR /><br />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\">The Weather Channel</a>)</p>\n",
      "excerpt": "Current Conditions: Fog, -28 C Forecast: Wed &#8211; Partly Cloudy. High: -15 Low: -26 Thu &#8211; Mostly Sunny. High: -20 Low: -24 Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather (provided by The Weather Channel)",
      "date": "2012-12-11 22:29:00",
      "modified": "2012-12-21 14:06:27",
      "categories": [],
      "tags": [],
      "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "url": "",
          "description": ""
      },
      "comments": [],
      "attachments": [],
      "comment_count": 0,
      "comment_status": "closed",
      "custom_fields": {
          "ecpt_chill": ["eqweqwe"]
      }
  }]
}
```

Looking at your code, you are looping over each key of the returned JSON. The first key is `status`, which, of course, doesn't have a `posts` property.

If you want to loop over the returned posts, you should do something like:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(i, item) {
```

and adjust your code to work with that.

Comment: Hi user2428118, thanks a lot. As soon as I have done changes it displays some more errors....

Comment: I looked up the syntax for [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and updated my answer.

Comment: That's simple tweak. Thanks a lot user2428118! You saved me a lot of time my friend.

Comment: Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/u2GQL/1/. By the way, since you're adding the returned data to the code directly, you may run into trouble with special characters such as `<` and `>`, if they happen to be included in the returned data.

Comment: Thank you again! Is there any way how to avoid these troubles with < and > symbols?

Comment: You could possibly create each element using `$('<ELEMENT>')` and then add the text like this: `$('<ELEMENT>').text(item.SOMETHING)` before appending them. For example, `output.append($('<h1>').text(item.title))`. This does not apply to `item.content` however, as it is already HTML.

Comment: By the way, if my answer has helped you, consider [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it.

Comment: I have just tested it in jsfiddle and it seems < and > are working fine but let me say again thank you for your help.

Comment: On a second thought, looking at the names `title` is also HTML (because there is also an item called `title_plain`. In that case, you can safely include it in your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the content you're trying to load. Undefined means you haven't properly loaded an object. Try to inspect the source content with something like Firefox's Poster extension.